# How to show success with multi insert inside function PDO PHP without javascript for processing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a function like this :

`rangking.inc.php`

```
function insert2(){     
    $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','')";
    foreach ($this->ik as $key => $value){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn[$key]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

but I'm stuck at how to count inserted have been done, and I want to show only one message for all values inserted.

can someone help me how to do?

here a piece of my code to show :

`rangking.php`

```
<?php
# include code

if($_POST){

    include_once 'path/rangking.inc.php';
    $eks = new rangking($db);

    $eks->ia = $_POST['ia'];
    $eks->ik = $_POST['ik'];
    $eks->nn = $_POST['nn'];

    # if($eks->insert2()){ using this code just throw me to false condition
?>
<!-- <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Berhasil Tambah Data!</strong> Tambah lagi atau <a href="rangking.php">lihat semua data</a>.
</div> -->
<?php
    # }

    # else{
?>
<!-- <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Gagal Tambah Data!</strong> Terjadi kesalahan, coba lagi.
</div> -->
<?php
    # }
}
?>
# below is all html code to show for form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function isn't returning anything

```
function insert2(){     
    $i = 0;

    $query = "insert into ".$this->table_name." values(?,?,?,'','')";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    foreach ($this->ik as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->ia);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->nn[$key]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i += 1;
    }

    return $i;

}
```

Comment: can you give me a logic about how my success doesn't show more success message in case you use `$i++`, i though it will show loop message depend of how much `$i++`, anyway, your code work like a charm, thanks

Comment: `$i++` and `$i += 1` are the same. I used the latter since I am more often on python than php.

Comment: yep I know that `$i++` and `$i+=1` are the same, but i just doesn't have a logic how it can be showing 1 message, even though if `foreach` loop for 2 times, so, `return $i` is `$i=1`, and i think it will show success message 2 times, sorry for another newbie question, _i've try to mark ur answer as correct, but it need more time,_

Comment: It will show it once because the return statement is outside the forloop. So the values 1,2,3, etc are only return once. But inside an `if` 1,2,3,.. all evaluate to `True` while 0 evaluates to `False`

Comment: ohh i see, so if i put `return` inside foreach, it would displaying success message as i though?

Comment: Not really, once the forloop reaches the break, it will stop looping at that point. What you are thinking of is yield http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php